# Heroku build failing after tweaking postinstall script

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, post-install

Well I am working on pull request on Heroku project I am experiencing following issue with it:

> > -----> Deleting 1 files matching .slugignore patterns.
> >     -----> Node.js app detected
> >     -----> Creating runtime environment
>
> ```
>    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
>    NODE_VERBOSE=false
>    NODE_ENV=production
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> ```
>
> -----> Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json):  9.3.0
>          engines.npm (package.json):   5.5.1
>
> ```
>    Resolving node version 9.3.0...
>    Downloading and installing node 9.3.0...
>    npm 5.5.1 already installed with node
> ```
>
> -----> Restoring cache
>          Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
>          - node_modules
>          - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
>   -----> Building dependencies
>          Installing node modules (package.json)
>   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_0205c32fc162b04a5bd36ce6d3e2a31a/GithubUsername-projName-45f1019/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   node lib/post_install.js
>   projName@0.3.0 postinstall /tmp/build_0205c32fc162b04a5bd36ce6d3e2a31a/GithubUserName-projName-45f1019
>   webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js --progress
>
> ```
>   90% chunk assets pro       Version: webpack 3.10.0
>    Time: 25301ms
>    Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>   ///All chunk files emitted details
>    projname.js    1.27 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
>    favicon.ico      17 kB          [emitted]
>    index.html    37.4 kB          [emitted]
>    [14] ./src/script.js 3.92 kB {0} [built]
>    //built details
>    + 208 hidden modules
>
>    ERROR in ./src/assetLoader.js
>    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './manifest' in '/tmp/build_0205c32fc162b04a5bd36ce6d3e2a31a/GithubUsername-projName-45f1019/src'
>    @ ./src/assetLoader.js 1:0-34
>    @ ./src/game.js
>    @ ./src/script.js
>
>    ERROR in proj.js from UglifyJs
>    Unexpected token: name (Creature) [GithubUsername-projName.js:1,99245]
>    Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>
>    [2] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html
> ```
>
> [built]
>          [4] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
>          [5] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
>          [6] ./assets/interface/AB.gif 82 bytes {0} [built]
>          [7] ./assets/interface/ProjPage.png 82 bytes {0} [built]
>          npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>          npm ERR! errno 2
>          npm ERR! projName@0.3.0 postinstall: `webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js --progress`
>          npm ERR! Exit status 2
>          npm ERR!
>          npm ERR! Failed at the projName@0.3.0 postinstall script.
>          npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> ```
>    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>    npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-03T13_35_09_304Z-debug.log
> ```
>
> -----> Build failed
>
> ```
>    We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>
>    If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>    https://help.heroku.com/
>
>    Love,
>    Heroku
>      !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
> ```

here is code for:

snippet of package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "compression": "^1.6.2",
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "jquery": "1.12.4",
        "jquery-mousewheel": "3.1.13",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "jquery.kinetic": "2.2.4",
        "jquery.transit": "0.9.12",
        "phaser-ce": "2.7.10",
        "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
        "socket.io-client": "1.3.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "eslint": "^4.12.1",
        "expose-loader": "^0.7.4",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "less": "^2.7.3",
        "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
        "prettier": "^1.8.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
    },

    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "postinstall": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js --progress",
        "build": "yarn run generateManifest && webpack --env.production",
        "build:dev": "yarn run generateManifest && webpack",
        "dev": "webpack --watch",
        "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
        "generateManifest": "node manifestGenerator.js"
    }
}
```

Server.js

```
// Setup basic express server
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var ip = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';
var gameManager = require('./server/gamemanager.js');
var qManager = require('./server/queuemanager.js');

// Setup the game queue and connection details
io.on('connection', function(session) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    // Store the username in the socket session for this client
    var username = makeid();
    session.username = username;

    // Add user to the queue
    qManager.addToQueue(session);

    session.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        qManager.removeFromQueue(session);
    });

    // Send user the username
    session.emit('login', session.username);

});


// Listen for server, and use static routing for deploy directory
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

app.use(express.static('./deploy', {
    maxAge: 86400000
}));
```

***webpack.config.js code***

```
 const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

// Are we in production
const production = process.env.production;

const baseSettings = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'script.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'deploy/'),
        filename: 'projname.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ogg|ico|cur|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/'),
            modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
            favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'favicon.ico')
        }),
    ]
}

const prodSettings = {
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ]
}

const devSettings = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
}

// Create either a production or development build depending on the `production` env setting
module.exports = merge(baseSettings, production ? devSettings : prodSettings);
```

I am not able to understand what the issue with web pack is their something wrong with my postinstall script? Am i missing any rules while tweaking script?

I tried applying some solutions from SO and Heroku documentation but nothing working ...Please Help !!!
Thank you in advance!!!
Feel free to comment for any other info.!!!

Comment: Hi. Please include the smallest code possible to replicate your problem. Please see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JakeSymons i understand that thats why worked on editing hope this helps in better understanding...!!!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?